# Setting Annotation Reference Scale to Zero

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.4, esri-geodatabase, annotation

I am creating annotation layers for a dispatch map. I'm trying to format my annotation layer to draw dynamically, with the font size remaining consistent across all scales. I must use an annotation layer because they will draw faster, and for the same reason am trying to stay away from creating multiple annotation layers with different reference scales.

ESRI's help documents explain that setting the reference scale of an annotation layer to zero will create the effect I'm looking for, but also that annotation feature classes stored in a geodatabase cannot be set to zero reference scale.

Does anyone have any knowledge of how to get my reference scale to zero?

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that setting the annotation reference scale to 0 is only possible for map annotation (those that are stored in the MDX) and not for geodatabase annotation (stored as a layer)

To change the reference scale of map annotation go to the data frame properties, choose the "annotation group" tab and after selecting the annotation group you want to modify click on the properties button (in my ArcGis 10.3 there are no ''0'' option but the 'none' option give the same result, ie. the annotation display at the same size regardless of the scale)

To change the reference scale of geodatabase annotation use ArcCatalog to access the properties of the annotation layer then choose the annotation tab (but you won't be able to set it to '0' or 'none', you have to input a "real" scale...)